# Are C++ functions in classes dynamically allocated?

Tags: c++, function, class, memory-management

```
class myclass{
 public: void hello(){
   std::cout<<"Hello"<<"\n";
 }
}
myclass* mc = new myclass;
mc->hello();
```

Is function `hello` dynamically allocated, or not dynamically allocated?

Comment: What do you mean? And there's no need for that pointer, just make an object.

Comment: I allocated that class dynamically, like `int* iptr = new int;`. And I want to know, if that function is somewhere in computer memory, or just in program space.

Comment: When dynamically allocating objects you just allocate space for particular instance data, functions are not data, they are code that is in the executable.

Comment: @AdrianLis data can also be in the executable.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, how dynamically allocated anything can be in executable data?

Comment: I didn't say that. I said that data can be in the executable.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Not to mention that on older machines, there wasn't any distinction between data and executable.

Comment: this is called citizenship. functions in C++ are third class citizens.

Answer (score 3):

Functions aren't objects (in C++ at least), and don't have lifetimes.  They're just there.  Always and forever.  (Again, from the C++ point of view.)

Comment: In that sample, yes. What about `std::function` or lambdas?

Comment: `std::function` (once instantiated) is an object of class type, as are lambdas.  They aren't functions, but rather functional objects.  But in both cases, the class type has a function `operator()()`, which is a function, doesn't have a lifetime, and is just there.

Comment: its not merely "just there", it has an address in the binary. it is a code segment, it has a well defined existence. Decided by the linker (and compiler has also responsibility for not having inlined).

Comment: @v.oddou In practice, yes.  If it's a member, you may not be able to get at this address directly; a pointer to member function isn't necessarily the address of the function, but a recipe of how to get that address (e.g. from the vtable).  (And of course, "always and forever", from the C++ point of view, only concerns the time span to which the C++ standard applies.)

Answer (score 3):

Functions are not "allocated" at all. Under the hood, a non-virtual function has no inherent physical attachment to the class. A member function is just a thin layer of syntactic sugar over an ordinary freestanding function. For example, in your case member function `hello` is translated into an ordinary freestanding function

```
void myclass_hello(myclass *this) {
  std::cout<<"Hello"<<"\n";
}
```

and when you call

```
mc->hello();
```

the compiler essentially replaces this call with

```
myclass_hello(mc);
```

In the early days of C++, when many C++ compilers were implemented as mere front ends for C compilers, this is exactly how C++ member functions were translated into C functions.

There's no difference in terms of "allocation" between member functions and ordinary freestanding functions. There's only one instance of member function that exists by itself, regardless of how many objects of that type you create.

With virtual functions things get a bit more complicated, but that still does not create any need for "allocation" of member functions. There's only one instance of each version of virtual member functions, and it still exists independently from the actual objects.

Comment: you can add that the virtual table "links" the class instances to the compiled functions in the binary by storing their address within the class instance itself. This allows indirect function calls. But like you said, the function virtuality does not affect its citizenship. just the wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

as you get into the internals of c++ you'll find the compiler does all sorts of crazy things to the code, such as completely change the name of your functions in order to support function  overloading.  A function is NOT  an object in C++, rather a reference to a table of functions.  I think what you're wondering is if you put a method outside a class is it better because there is not a "copy" for each instance of the class.  The truth is that you don't get a "copy" of the function, but do get a copy of the pointer variable? The answer is no, c++ will just analyze the code and put that single function call wherever you use it.  Any reference so "this" or instance data will be taken into account when it translates the variable names in the code to actual memory locations.

Answer (score 0):

There is no allocation of memory when functions are involved.

These are just a bunch of code in your executable

Comment: the OS has to allocate some space to hold your executable when it gets launched.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one instance of the actual code for `hello` and it is in the executable file/loaded into memory when the program is run.  All instances of the class (objects) use the one instance of the code.

Answer (score 0):

The machine code for your hello method is generated at compile time.  Since it is not a virtual method, the compiler can determine how to call it directly.  Equivalent code might be:

```
struct MyStruct {};
void hello(MyStruct* this)
{
  std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
}
int main(int, char**)
{
  MyStruct* ms = new MyStruct;
  hello(ms);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on the context, more precisely what kind of function it is.
You never allocate a function, since it's code not data, the only thing that can be dynamic is what functions are called on per-class basis, these are the virtual functions.

This is a normal class member function :

```
void MyClass::CallFunction()
{
}
```

In reality the compiler, and just C++ lots of compilers do this, add a normally "invisible" but at the same time accessible function parameter which is usually the first in the list, the class object's memory pointer, *this.

```
void MyClass::CallFunction(MyClass *this)
{
}
```

IF you declare the member function **static** , you basically create a function that is in the scope of the class but not part of the class, thus it doesn't have a this pointer.

Because of scoping, the compiler automatically refers to your class variables so you don't have to, so anything that belongs to the class object is accessed with

```
this->classVariable = 0;
```

For virtual functions the compiler created a vtable that is handled by the compiler so function overriding and polymorphism can actually work. The vtable only stores pointers to the functions so even in this case functions are fixed.

It's up to the compiler to decide what parts to actually allocate in a class object, these are usually non-const non-static member variables, so you can think of the actual object as a simple struct of all the variables present in all of the sub classes and your main class.